# Enable XRAY on a lambda function using AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-xray

What is the recommended way to do enable XRAY on a Lambda function using AWS Amplify?

- Edit the CloudFormation that Amplify generates?
- Use CDK somehow to edit the function after it's been deployed?  *How?*
- Some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edit the CloudFormation that Amplify generates

1. Set [TracingConfig's mode to 'Active` in the AWS::Lambda::Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#cfn-lambda-function-tracingconfig).
2. Make sure your Lambda's role has permissions for X-Ray

```
"xray:PutTraceSegments",
"xray:PutTelemetryRecords"
```